# Linksys WRT54G router broadcasting, but not responding otherwise

Tags: openwrt, wrt54g

I was messing with my WRT54G running OpenWRT and I may have ruined it, but I am not sure.

By default, it has a static IP of 192.168.1.1, but I turned that off and made so it gets its IP from DHCP. After changing that setting, I cannot get to the admin panel, but I still see it broadcasting the WLAN. Pinging 192.168.1.1 times out. I had it configured to use a custom hostname, but that address does not respond either.

I tried the following:

- Using nmap to scan on 192.168.1.1-255 to find where it is now (from a PC hooked up via  ethernet), but nothing came up
- Factory resetting using different methods from online, and nothing has reset it
- Using the Linksys tftp utility to flash a new firmware image (but since I can't find the IP of the router, I can't do it)

Is it bricked, or am I doing something wrong? Is there a good way to find the IP?

Thank you for your time.

**EDIT:** As per Nic's suggestion, I made my router use another DHCP server (a second router) and could find the IP. I then restarted both routers and I can now connect. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have some other DHCP server on your LAN? If not, try adding another router to act as the DHCP server then see if you can find your Linksys.

Comment: Ok, how can I do that? Should I just hook the routers up directly with an ethernet cable?

Comment: Yes, just connect the LAN ports of two routers together, then connect your computer to a LAN port on either router.

Comment: Ok, I found the router and I can ping it, but I still can't connect. I did an nmap scan of it and no ports are listening.

Comment: Maybe try TFTP again now that you know the IP address? That's all I've got though. Good luck.

Comment: TFTP did not work on that IP. Thanks for getting me this far :D

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I know is to make a 30/30/30-Reset. The IP was resetted in all routers I had. (http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Hard_reset_or_30/30/30). Maybe you want to flash DD-WRT right afterwards.